# Error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Tags: pandas

I am importing my data like this:

```
new=pd.read_csv('/My Drive/DYZ2013.txt')
new.columns = new.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
new.index = pd.to_datetime(new.Date + ' ' + new.Time)
new['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(new.Date)
new['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(new['Time'], format=' %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
```

The data looks like this:

```
                        Date        Time            Close
2013-01-04 07:00:00.000 2013-01-04  07:00:00        7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.100 2013-01-04  07:00:00.100000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.200 2013-01-04  07:00:00.200000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.300 2013-01-04  07:00:00.300000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.400 2013-01-04  07:00:00.400000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.500 2013-01-04  07:00:00.500000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.600 2013-01-04  07:00:00.600000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.700 2013-01-04  07:00:00.700000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.800 2013-01-04  07:00:00.800000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.900 2013-01-04  07:00:00.900000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.100 2013-01-04  07:00:00.100000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.110 2013-01-04  07:00:00.110000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.120 2013-01-04  07:00:00.120000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.130 2013-01-04  07:00:00.130000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.140 2013-01-04  07:00:00.140000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.150 2013-01-04  07:00:00.150000 7846
2013-01-04 07:00:00.160 2013-01-04  07:00:00.160000 7846
```

and when trying to plot the time series with this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(new['Time'], new['Close'], label='price')
plt.vlines(datetime.date(2016,4, 20), 0, 270, linestyles='--', colors='gray', label='Train/Test data cut-off')
plt.xlabel('Date_ Time')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.title('Figure 2: price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

How do I plot my data using the index or any other date+time?

Comment: Which line do you get the error? Can you show your error stack?

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-2d7085aa9486> in <module>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
----> 2 plt.plot(new['Time'], new['Close'], label='price')
      3 plt.vlines(datetime.date(2016,4, 20), 0, 270, linestyles='--', colors='gray', label='Train/Test data cut-off')
      4 plt.xlabel('Date_ Time')
      5 plt.ylabel('USD')